# pandas cumulative subtraction in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I need to do a burndown starting from the baseline and subtracting all the values along, essentially I'm looking for an **opposite of DataFrame().cumsum(0)**:

```
               In Use
Baseline       3705.0
February 2018     0.0
March 2018        2.0
April 2018       15.0
May 2018         30.0
June 2018        14.0
July 2018       797.0
August 2018    1393.0
September 2018   86.0
October 2018    374.0
November 2018    21.0
December 2018     0.0
January 2019      0.0
February 2019     0.0
March 2019        0.0
April 2019        2.0
unknown         971.0
```

I cannot find a function to do or, or I'm not looking by the right tags / names.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) by groups created by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), comapring by [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) `<` and cumulative sum:

```
g = df['Use'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
df['new'] = df['Use'].groupby(g).diff().fillna(df['Use'])
print (df)
                In     Use     new
0         Baseline  3705.0  3705.0
1    February 2018     0.0     0.0
2       March 2018     2.0     2.0
3       April 2018    15.0    13.0
4         May 2018    30.0    15.0
5        June 2018    14.0    14.0
6        July 2018   797.0   783.0
7      August 2018  1393.0   596.0
8   September 2018    86.0    86.0
9     October 2018   374.0   288.0
10   November 2018    21.0    21.0
11   December 2018     0.0     0.0
12    January 2019     0.0     0.0
13   February 2019     0.0     0.0
14      March 2019     0.0     0.0
15      April 2019     2.0     2.0
16         unknown   971.0   969.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.diff` with `fillna`. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 5)})

df['B'] = df['A'].cumsum()
df['C'] = df['B'].diff().fillna(df['B']).astype(int)

print(df)

   A   B  C
0  1   1  1
1  4   5  4
2  4   9  4
3  2  11  2
4  1  12  1
```